# Редирект /?post_type=product&p=140

Tags: редирект

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать редирект с ссылки на главную? допустим с https://test.com.ua/?post_type=product&p=140 на https://test.com.ua

Comment: а на чем этот редирект хотите сделать? nginx/apache/iis, в коде на php, python, perl, asp.net

Comment: Apache.. Нужно прописать в .htaccess - wordpress

Comment: https://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/redirect_url.txt.html `Redirect permanent /?post_type=product&p=140 /` если я правильно понимаю

Comment: Не работает....